# create a Save As file in regard to a specified sequence of numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get VBA to to save a file dependent upon the first three sequenced numbers in a 9 digit number. The number looks something like this: 400-134004. I need to make three different files depending on the first sequence of numbers, they are 400, 401, 402. How do I go about it, or what is wrong with my code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim String_1 As String
        Dim String_2 As String
        Dim String_3 As String

        String_1 = "400"
        String_2 = "401"
        String_2 = "402"

  If Not Range("A1").Value = "" And Not Range("B1").Value = "" And Not Range("C1").Value = "" Then

  If Left(String_1, 3).Range("C1").Select Then
        '400 = 312B
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1:C1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = Fa
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="u:\CSV\Diepunch400.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close (SaveChange = False)
  Else

  End If

  If Left(String_2, 3).Range("C1").Select Then
        '401 = 312HTG
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1:C1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = Fa
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="u:\CSV\Diepunch401.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close (SaveChange = False)
   Else

   End If

       If Left(String_3, 3).Range("C1").Select Then
        '402 = 312HTX
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1:C1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = Fa
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="u:\CSV\Diepunch402.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close (SaveChange = False)
    Else

    End If




     Else

     End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: one glaring issue is this line is not correct syntax: `If Left(String_2, 3).Range("C1").Select` *(and all lines like it)*

Comment: Unclear what `Left(String_1, 3).Range("C1").Select` is supposed to do.

Comment: Also, the `Fa` in `Application.CutCopyMode = Fa` is an uninitialized variable, so it will be 0.  It expects `xlCopy` or `xlCut`, which are 1 and 2 respectively, so that will error as well.

Comment: also, are you sure you want this done on the `Worksheet_Change` event? It will fire **everytime** you make a change on your sheet (especially because you don't really filter on Target cell).

Comment: @ScottHoltzman It does not matter if it fires every time the only purpose of this code is create a file that another program then sees and initiates its purpose.

Comment: @Comintern I am trying to get his code to select the first three digits from a sequence of numbers that is stored in range C1. Basically I have a bar-code and i scan it. It then sends three sequences of number to cells A1 B1 and C1 respectively, I need the code to read the first three numbers from cell C1 to determine what file to save to a folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 Dim String_1 As String
 Dim String_2 As String
 Dim String_3 As String

 String_1 = "400"
 String_2 = "401"
 String_3 = "402"

 If Len(Range("A1").Value) > 0 And Len(Range("B1").Value) > 0 And Len(Range("C1").Value) > 0 Then 

   Dim sComp as String
   sComp = Left(Range("C1"),3)

     If sComp = String_1 or sComp = String_2 or sComp = String_3 Then

        Range("A1:C1").Copy
        Dim wbCopy as Workbook
        Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Add

        With wbCopy
           .Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
           .SaveAs Filename:="u:\CSV\Diepunch" & sComp & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
           .Close False
        End With

    End If

 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Yup that worked, I'll have to modify to create different files, but this works thank you.